# Can I use an integration spec to catch a weird jquery bug?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rspec

The clientside code my my application has the worst bug you can ever encounter: an intermittent bug.

Basically, my system retrieves users that fall within a certain age group. Each age group is requested via an html button. When you click the button, the users are retrieved via an ajax request and then an area slides down to display these certain users.

Here's the code snippet that fires when the button is clicked:

```
$.getJSON('/users/' + age_group {

    $.each(data, function(index, value){
        users.push(value.name);
    });

    $(area).empty();

    $.each(users, function(index, value){
        $(area).append("<div> <span class = 'pull-left user unstyled'></span>" + value + '</div>');
    });

}).done(function(){
    $(area).stop().slideDown(200, function(){

        $('body').click(function(ev){   
            $(area).stop().slideUp(200)
        });
    });
});
```

What's frustrating is that 99% of the time, the `$(area)` div slides down the exact correct amount to display all of the users (courtesy of the `slideDown` function), but that one time in a hundred it doesn't quite slide, the appended users popout of the `$(area)` div and the whole layout breaks.

I could fashion a workaround (maybe `overflow: hidden` on the `$(area)`; at least the layout wouldn't break) but the thing is this bug is ridiculously intermittent. Seriously one time in a hundred.

My application uses a capybara rspec selenium stack to run integration specs, and I have seen the bug manifest in firefox a few times (in identical specs it doesn't appear at all), so is it possible to use the stack to find out what's causing this error? How would you detect if the layout has broken? All the elements are present on the page? **Maybe div height? Can I test the '$(area)' div's height to make sure it's height = y if x number of results are retrieved?** The error appears to be completely random. With rspec, can I create some kind of log of the html, the database and save a screenshot (I think you can do this with selenium) ONLY when the height is an unexpected value?

Is this an industry practise? Jquery is by far the glitchiest area of webdesign, and yet googling 'jquery behaviour driven development' doesn't yield much. Does one use rspec to test jquery code? Or is there some other gem out there?

To be fair, this isn't the title of the question, but I would be eternally grateful if someone could tell me why they think this is happening? Is this a jquery bug? Is the `slideDown` method known to occasionally not slide down enough? **What makes me think it's a jquery bug is the fact that sometimes the `$(area)` div doesn't just slide down not enough, but it slides down to the height of the last group of requested users, as though that variable has been cached somehow by jquery.**

Conclusion:

- Can a div's height be retrieved and tested via capybara rspec selenium?
- What's the correct way to log information with rspec?
- Can I take a screenshot with capybara rspec selenium?
- How does one develop clientside code in a test-driven fashion?
- Does anyone know of a glitch in jquery's `slideDown` function?

Comment: since you are using ajax to retrieve the data, why not replace the whole div that the displays the data? you can use jasmine to test the javascript.

Comment: I'm putting this as a comment as this might not be the answer you're looking for. There are a couple of things you can do to prevent some weird behaviours: for instance, make sure the user can't double-click the html button - remove or disable the button until you retrieve the results. I have a feeling it's `.stop()` that is causing this. I would also transform this script to a module or something and test it using jasmin as pointed out by @prasad.surase, especially if it's critical to your app.

Comment: Thanks so much, jasmine's really what I was looking for! And thanks H-man for that tip of disabling the button. But why would `.stop()` cause this error? I thought all `.stop()` did was clear the animation queue (*not* including the animation currently running)?

Comment: @H-man You were dead right about the `.stop()` and I like the look of [Jasmin](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem)....you've helped me out a lot, do you want to create an answer :) I am interested into why .stop() does this though..I mean like I say I didn't think it stopped the current animation? Should stop only be used to stop animation build up on hover-overs?